# Jquery add index to name attribute when adding input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a dynamic table. Below is the Jquery for add function. Does anyone know how to dynamically change var "i" in the name attribute of the input field? For example, when I add row one, it should be uploadForms[1].name. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var i=1;
 $("#add").click(function(){  
 var input1 = $(document.createElement('input'))
 .attr("name", "uploadForms[i].name");
 input1.appendTo("#uploadFormsTable");
 })
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `.attr("name", "uploadForms[i].name");` to `.attr("name", "uploadForms["+i+"].name");` so you can access to the variable instead of applying a string

Comment: upvote please if it is the correct answer to your question ;) @SophiaWu